# programatically login to web application with windows authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, ntlm

I am working on a MEAP (Mobile Ent. Application  platform) which uses PHP on server side and javascript on client side. The web application is consumed through an appshell (hybrid app) on IOS devices. The application also stores the userid and password so user doesn't have to enter it again.

We also have a portal link (portal in SharePoint) in this application which user click and it launches the Safari which again presents login prompt to user. (windows authentication to sharepoint).

Is it possible to somehow pass the userid/password to safari so it will automatically login to sharepoint portal??

I just need to know the best approach to follow in this scenario?

According to my knowledge, the sharepoint uses NTLM authentication so I tried creating Ajax call by passing NTLM authorization header, but it doesn't work?

I used below js to create NTLM authentication.

https://github.com/erlandranvinge/ntlm.js

Answer (score 0):

Since you are launching safari, you can pass it a url. Why not pass query parameters to the url and get the credentials from there?

Ofcourse, this will require a slight modification of the sharepoint side, a small javascript will do.

Comment: I am very sorry but I didn't get your point clearly. Yes. I can launch Safari and I can pass query parameters but since SP is configured with windows authentication, how this will work? Can you pls. elaborate this further?